# Error in output in c++ program

Tags: c++

The purpose of the program is to read a phrase from a file into a vector and convert the phrase into Pig Latin. When the translated phrase is outputted in Pig Latin, an additional "ay" is added after the phrase (which is not supposed to happen). Can anyone spot why this is happening? It is important that I fix this because it affects the total letters and total characters of the Pig Latin phrase that I need to output. Also, I'm not asking anyone to write any code for me, but any tips on how to make my code less redundant. A portion of my grade for programs is efficiency, which I usually lose points on.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
  ifstream in;
  string word, fileName;
  vector <string> phrase;
  int length = 0, index = 0;
  int totalWords = -1, totalLetters = -3, totalChars;

  cout << "PIG LATIN PROGRAM" << endl; 
  cout << "Which file are you accessing? : ";
  cin >> fileName;

  fileName += ".txt";

  in.open(fileName);

  if (in.fail()) cout << "\nFile not found!" << endl;

  while(getline(in, word)) phrase.push_back(word);

  cout << "Original Phrase: " << phrase[0] << endl;

  istringstream iss(phrase[0]);

  cout << "Pig Latin phrase: ";
  do { 
    string OGword;
    string PLword;

    for (int i=0; i < phrase.size(); i++){ 
      iss >> OGword;
      totalWords++;
    }

    if (OGword[0]=='a' || OGword[0]=='A' || OGword[0]=='e' || OGword[0]=='E' || OGword[0]=='i' || OGword[0]=='I' || OGword[0]=='o' || OGword[0]=='O' || OGword[0]=='u' || OGword[0]=='U'){ 

      cout << OGword << "way" << " ";
      totalLetters += (OGword.size() + 3);
    }
    else {

      PLword = OGword.substr(index);
      length = PLword.length();

      PLword.insert(length, "ay");
      PLword.insert(length, 1, OGword[index]);
      PLword.erase(0, 1);
      if (isupper(OGword[0])){ 
        transform(PLword.begin(), PLword.end(), PLword.begin(), ::tolower); 
        (toupper(PLword[1]));
        char    upper;

        upper = toupper(PLword[0]);
        PLword.erase(0, 1);
        cout << upper;           
      }
      cout << PLword << " ";  
      totalLetters += PLword.size();
    }      
  } while (iss);  

  totalChars = totalLetters + 1;

  cout << "\n\nTotal words: " << totalWords << endl;
  cout << "Total Letters: " << totalLetters << endl;
  cout << "Total Characters: "<< totalChars << endl;
}
```

Comment: Many programming text editors and Integrated Development Environments have a built in formatter. For example, I've washed your code through the one in Eclipse (after a few settings tweaks to get the look I want) and it comes out looking reasonably slick. Bad indentation can hide bugs. Handy tip: You can use the `tolower` or `toupper` functions to halve the number of tests in the vowel-finding `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The core loop of the program looks like this (in pseudocode):

```
istringstream iss; // Contains line of text.
do {
    string OGword;

    get_OGword_and_count_totalWords(iss, OGword);
    print_pig_latin_of_word(OGword);
} while (iss);
```

The loop runs as long as `iss` has not experienced an error.  And in particular, `iss` does not experience an error until an extraction operation fails.  So things happen in the loop like this:

- OGword contains the last legitimate word on the line.
- Print the last word.
- The `while` clause is tested.  `iss` is still good at this point because no error has occurred, even if `iss` is at the end of string.
- Attempt to extract a word into `OGword`.  This fails, and leaves `OGword` empty ("").
- Print the Pig Latin version of "", which is "ay".
- The `while` clause is tested.  `iss` is in an error state, and the loop ends.

### Fix

One possible fix out of many is to test `iss` for an error immediately after extracting a word.

```
std::istringstream iss; // Contains line of text
std::string OGword;
while (iss >> OGword) {
    increment_word_total();
    print_pig_latin_of_word(OGword);
}
```

In this version, the operation `iss >> OGword` returns `iss`, which is converted to `bool`.  If there was an error during the immediately preceeding extraction, the loop ends without printing anything.

### Other Advice

I think the best way to improve readability is to break the code up into smaller functions.  For instance, take the if / else block that formats and prints the Pig Latin, and actually put it in a function:

```
int print_pig_latin_of_word_and_return_total_letters(string_view word);
```

Then, the code in that function can be further subdivided:

```
bool starts_with_vowel(std::string_view word);
int print_vowel_word_and_count_letters(std::string_view word);
int print_consonant_word_and_count_letters(std::string_view word);

int print_pig_latin_of_word_and_count_letters(std::string_view word) {
    if (starts_with_vowel(word)) {
        return print_vowel_word_and_count_letters(word);
    } else {
        return print_consonant_word_and_count_letters(word);
    }
}
```

### Odds and Ends

I would drop `using namespace std` and write all of the std library names as `std::string`, etc.  This makes it clear which things are from the standard library.

The program has interesting behavior on input files that contain more than one line.  There is a `for` loop that loops over `phrase.size()` which is number of input lines.  This causes words to be skipped and `totalWords` to be incorrect.

This statement doesn't do anything, because the result of `toupper` is ignored:

```
(toupper(PLword[1]));
```